# SentenceTransformer (SBERT): encode_multi_process(): difference between batch_size and chunk_size

Tags: chunks, sentence-transformers

- :param **batch_size**: Encode sentences with batch size
- :param **chunk_size**: Sentences are chunked and sent to the individual processes.

Assuming I have a few thousands sentences to encode on 4 CPU cores.

I believe I understand what batch_size means. A batch_size of 32 would mean that groups of 32 sentences would be sent together to be encoded (normal batch processing meaning for deep learning).

If I run 4 processes (4 CPU cores), batches of 32 sentences would be sent to each core to be encoded.

I don't see what "chunk_size" is for... or what it means in this context.
Thanks for any help, clarification, and your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a list of sentences to the transformer to encode. When running in parallel there are multiple transformers of number performing encoding.

- Each transformer performs encoding in a batch, that is the batch size.
- Each of the transformers receive a chunk of the total list to process at a time, that is the chunk size.

In summary, the chunk size has to do with how many sentences each transformer receives at a time to process, the batch size is internal to the transformer on how many sentences are processed together.